# How to access elasticsearch in EC2?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I am new with AWS, and recently spun up an EC2 instance, and installed elasticsearch on it. I can now access elasticesearch via http://localhost:9200 after ssh into the box, but I am a little stuck on how to access this from external.

What's the best practice if I would like to write some app to access this EC2 instance? And how can I configure it so it can be access externally?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us the "Network and HTTP" part of your elasticsearch.yml configuration file, specifically "network.bind_host" ?

Comment: I resolved this issue by using SSH tunneling.